# Change logo image in VLC player dynamically

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, video-streaming, vlc

I want to control VLC player via command line in windows 7 64 bit. I want to overlay an image in particular position on a video stream. This can be done easily via vlc command line option.
Now I want to change this logo image while video is playing. Is there any way to o it? ie change logo image while vlc player play some video.

I will call this commands from net beans Java....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/). (I never used it but looking at the listed features it seems like it's capable of what you are trying to achieve.)